# wcf contract location

Tags: wcf

I have the following setup: 
Main assembly that contains a WcfService and IWcfService contract.
Satellite assembly that creates a channel and invokes a method on IWcfService. In order to get that contract it references the Main assembly.

The problem: Up until recently both assemblies were compiled against .NET 2.0. Now the Main assembly needs to be compiled against .NET 4.0. The Satellite assembly cannot be targeting 4.0 because it has to run within 2.0 process (not mine).

The question: In what other way I can provide the IWcfService contract to the satellite assembly so I don't have to reference the Main assembly?

Thanks,
Roman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would it work to just do it with a third assembly that contains just the `IWcfService` contract and is referenced by both Main and Satellite assemblies? The new assemblye would target .NET 2.0 so it could be referenced from both.

Comment: This is the obvious choice indeed. I was wondering if there is any other way, I don't really like to introduce a whole new assembly just for one file. Something maybe in XML format.

Comment: Definitely understand. Though I will say its certainly pretty common to have an assembly just for your interfaces/contracts. Though in your case its just one, so I definitely see why you'd rather avoid that.

Comment: I like Tim's approach.  Nothing wrong with an itty-bitty assembly.  :)

Comment: Oh well, I did find another IWcfService contract, so now a separate Contracts assembly is somewhat justified. :)